# Orbeon - change font to get polish letters

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm using Polish characters in forms. Unfortunately, during the generation of the PDF file in automatic mode, all Polish diacritical characters are not printed (ie: text 'zażółć gęślą jaźń' is printed as 'zaó gl ja'). I tried to set properties in file properties-local.xml:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.pdf.template.font.path.vera" value="path_to_font/font.ttf"/>

<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.pdf.font.family.vera" value="Arial"/>
```

or with wildcards:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.pdf.template.font.path.*" value="path_to_font/font.ttf"/>

<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.pdf.font.family.*" value="Arial"/>
```

I tested PDF generation with different fonts, but it didn't work. I didn't even notice font style changes in PDF. So there is a question, what should be done to properly print the Polish characters in the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

These properties are for the template mode, and they won't work for the automatic mode. Try instead:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.pdf.font.path.vera"
    value="path_to_font/font.ttf"/>

<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.pdf.font.family.vera"
    value="Arial"/>
```

See also the [doc](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Font-embedding-in-automatic-mode).