# Orbeon - How to use relative path for the embedded PDF font?

Tags: orbeon

We are having a problem with the encoding of Eastern European letters in the generated PDFs, and I found a solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281441/orbeon-change-font-to-get-polish-letters). However this only seems to work when i use the absolute path to the font, which is a bit of an issue when we deploy to multiple servers where this changes, and where I'm not guaranteed to know the full path.

I have placed the font in /resources/fonts/ and have tried the following for "oxf.fr.pdf.font.path":

1. "/fonts/font.ttf" - Which is the same format as the one working for oxf.fr.css.custom.uri.*
2. "oxf:/fonts/font.ttf" - Which is the one working for oxf.fb.toolbox.group.text.uri.*
3. I've tried using ${catalina.base}
4. I've tried hosting the font on the webserver and using the direct URL.

All to no avail. I'm hoping you will be able to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible right now, because the path is passed directly to the iText library, which expects to load it from the filesystem, not from Orbeon Forms's resource managers.

Comment: Ah I see. That also explains why none of my tries worked. I'll try to get around it using string substitution on deploy then.

Comment: That makes sense. I hope the workaround works for you!